# R - Insert value into new row based on another dataframe

Tags: r

Dataframe_1

```
    Name  Value
    a      4
    b      5
    c      7
    d      9
```

Dataframe_2

```
    Name Mass
    a     131
    c     140
    b     110
    d     90
```

I want the following result:

```
   Name  Value   Mass
   a      4      131
   b      5      110
   c      7      140
   d      9      90
```

I did this originally as the following but now I have dataframe_2 that I want to get the value from

```
   Dataframe_1$Mass <- gsub("a", 131, Dataframe_1$Name)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just looking to merge them? I would just merge:

```
merged <- merge(dataframe_1,dataframe_2, by="Name", all=TRUE) #all
merged <- merge(dataframe_1,dataframe_2, by="Name", all.x =TRUE) #dataframe 1 full
```

Comment: Not all values in dataframe_1 are found in dataframe_2, in other words dataframe_2 is incomplete. In cases where the Name is not in dataframe_2, I don't want to lose the data

Comment: Gotcha - was just working off the desired set - to get the full outer join use all=TRUE.

Comment: Thank you for your solution Hatt

Comment: No problem, happy to help when I can.

Answer (score 2):

The `merge` function is the tool you need :)
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html

e.g. if your two data.frames are called `dt1` and `dt2`, you would use `dtnew <- merge(dt1, dt2, by = "Name")`

There are variables for controlling different types of joins e.g.
[How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Fwwiw, for future-proofing answers, folks usually refer to `?merge` instead of external links.

Comment: Thank you for your solution Jonny